# how do i install beautiful soup for python on my mac? see error

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.3 on a Macbook Pro. It came with Python 2.7.1 installed. I need the beautiful soup library. So I did the following:

1) went to crummy.com and downloaded beautifulsoup4-4.0.2.tar.gz

2) uncompressed it

3) navigated to uncompressed directory and typed the following

```
python setup.py install
```

but i got a error that i couldn't write to some directory.

4) so i ran:

sudo python setup.py install

No Errors! Good, right? Not exactly. When I try to run a program with the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
```

I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your error messages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For BeautifulSoup4 you have to use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Check the document: [BS4 document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: After looking at about 6 different pages for this error, finally, this one provided the answer. Thank you so much. That BS4 document is damned long, you know ...

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you can't use `pip` or `easy_install`? Unless you're set on installing from source, you can run either of the following:

```
$ easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

Or, if you have `pip` (which I recommend, you can install it with `easy_install pip`):

```
$ pip install BeautifulSoup
```

I'm not certain why your source install isn't working though. Is it possible the python interpreter you're using to install the source and the interpreter you're using in your program are different? Try running `python --version` on the command line--is the same version displayed as when you run the following in your program?

```
import sys
print sys.version  # => '2.7.2 (default, Feb  4 2012, 02:01:30)...
```

Comment: Note that this will install BeautifulSoup3, which is no longer recommended by the author.

Comment: The problem is NOT the install. The problem is that there are lots and lots of tutorials and such that say: "from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup" when what is needed NOW is "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" ... and this page is the only place where I found that answer.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't aware BeautifulSoup had changed so drastically.